# how to use find command to get the filename in cygwin?

Tags: r

There is a directory in `C:\R-3.0.2\R-3.0.2\src\library\stats\R`,a file  which contains the character `loess`, i want to get the file name ,why i can't get it ?

```
 find /cygdrive/c/R-3.0.2     -name  "loess"
```

I can get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match files named `loess` exactly:

```
find /cygdrive/c/R-3.0.2     -name  "loess"
```

This will match files that contain "loess" in the name, for example `loess123`, `hello-loess`, `loess`:

```
find /cygdrive/c/R-3.0.2     -name  "*loess*"
```